# Help With NSNotifcation and Asynchronous Downloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser, nsnotificationcenter

I am sending a notification from one view to another view. My problem is that the notification in the view that I am calling in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method is only getting sent when the tableview is scrolling. How can I stop this and make it send the notification once the images have downloaded? Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/756302

Thanks

MKDev

Comment: xcode is just an IDE, and has nothing to do with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understand your code, the message will trigger the reload of the whole table. That should lead to a refresh of the cells.

Thus, you'll need to check in line 76, if the cell is being drawn because a reload was triggered from the finish-message (and the image is now ready to display) or if you need to start the asynchronous download of the image.

The first thing which comes into my mind to check this is to set a property in reloadTableView:

```
- (void)reloadTableView
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"aaa"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"name" object:nil];
    NSLog(@"removeobserver");
    loadImageFinished = YES;
    // if your table has several sections you'll need to adopt the section number 
    NSIndexSet *indices = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:indices withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [indices release];
}
```

and then to add in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...
   if (loadImageFinished) {
      ... 
   } else {
      [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathImage]];
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that there could be other reasons why the table is being reloaded - the view could have been disappeared or unloaded and you might not wish to trigger your asynnchronous loading several times.

Comment: My problem is that the tableView is not getting reloaded when the images have downloaded. The tableView only gets reloaded when it is scrolling. Have you any idea how to fix that?

Comment: but you're sure the 'reloadTableView' is being called in between? I modified my code again - replaced reloadData. This transition, I use in my code to switch to a different cell-style for editing.

Comment: reloadTableView is only being called when the tableview is scrolled.

Comment: That sounds strange. Who is the caller? From your code, it should only be called when the notification is sent. Maybe you should try to rename it, just in case it collides with a UITableView-method?

Comment: The caller is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method: [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathImage]];

Comment: But only very indirectly. The idea of your code - as far as I understood - is to send a message once the download finished from connectionDidFinishLoading to the rootviewcontroller to refresh the tableView accordingly. It looks like you took the code from [here](http://blog.163.com/lionyue@126/blog/static/1079307120096895433277/); did you try to ask the original author?

Comment: Sorry - tried to get your code running; but I'm missing too many parts as to be able to quickly get to checking it at runtime. Try adding 'NSLog's to all important places to be able to see in the console what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work right, when the `connectionDidFinishLoading`, you call the `NSNotificationCenter` to send the notification, there is no post method in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: ah. Basically the tableView needs to be reloaded when the connectDidFinishLoading, So I was trying to send a notification from the asyncView to the rootviewcontroller to tell the tableView to reload. Please could you tell me how I can do this without having to wait until the tableview has scrolled?